# nginx cache slice-by-slice and browser cache

Tags: caching, nginx, browser, slice

I'm using "Filling the Cache Slice-by-Slice" from this article https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/mycache keys_zone=mycache:10m;

server {
    listen 80;

    proxy_cache mycache;

    slice              1m;
    proxy_cache_key    $host$uri$is_args$args$slice_range;
    proxy_set_header   Range $slice_range;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_valid  200 206 1h;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://origin:80;
    }
}
```

nginx is caching video from server, but browser is not caching video. Help me please.

Comment: I don't see where do you tell browser to cache response.

Comment: Because, that common ways doesn't works. For example, adding to location block "expires 3d;" not helping.

Comment: Example headers:
Cache-Control:max-age=259200
Connection:close
Content-Length:9780618
Content-Range:bytes 440-9781057/9781058
Content-Type:video/webm;charset=UTF-8
Date:Thu, 19 May 2016 16:06:01 GMT
Expires:Sun, 22 May 2016 16:06:01 GMT
Server:nginx/1.9.15

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved problem. I'm added ETag and Last-Modified on backend.